How to get the minimum time and the initial adjoint in control problem?
I am trying to implement a shooting algorithm to solve a atate-to-state transfer of two-level quantum system. The Hamiltonian of the system is given by
$$\hat{H} = \frac{u_x}{2}\hat{\sigma}_x + \frac{u_y}{2}\hat{\sigma}_y$$
We can describe the state of the system in terms of Bloch coordinates $(x,y,z)$:
$$\begin{cases} \dot{x}=u_yz\\ \dot{y} = -u_xz \\ \dot{z}= -u_yx + u_xy\end{cases}$$
The goal of the control problem is to bring the system from $(1,0,0)$ to $(0,1,0)$ in minimum time with the constrait $u_x^2 +u_y^2 = 1$. So, we can use the PMP (Pontryagin Maximum Principle) and the Pontryagin Hamiltonian can be expressd as
$$H_p = u_x(p_zy-p_yz) + u_y(p_xz -p_zx) + p_0$$
where $(p_xp_y,p_x)$ is the adjoint state wich also satisfies the Bloch equation, and $p_0$ the abnormal multiplier. The maximization condition of $H_p$ leads in the regular case to the following optimal controls
$$u_x = (p_zy-p_yz)/H$$
$$u_y = (p_xz-p_zx)/H$$
where $H = \sqrt{(p_zy-p_yz)^2 + (p_xz -p_zx)^2}$.
This control problem can be integrated exactly and I want the find the minimum time $t_f$ and the initial adjoint state.
My attempt: we case write the Hamiltonian system
$$\begin{cases} \dot{x}_i = \frac{\partial H_p}{\partial p_i} \\ \dot{p}_i = -\frac{\partial H_p}{\partial x_i} \end{cases}$$
I know that if I add the partial equations of the 6 Hamiltonian equations and if I  add more 4 equations, three for $p_i$ and 1 for the time. Just integrate for a large time $t$ and one initial adjoint random and I will found the minimnum time $t_f$ and the initial adjoint ideal.
My doubt is: I don't know last four equations. I just know that dependes of inicial guess adjoint state. I thing I am close, but far in same way.
How do I get the minimum time and the initial adjoint? Thanks for any advance.
